# Recaptcha sent a token. But I don't know what to do in Android - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, recaptcha

My question is as in the title. I started a recaptcha client by reading Android's documentation. As a result of the transactions, he sent me a long token. However, no recaptcha window appeared on the screen. What will I do with this token and how will I open a recaptcha window to verify the user? Thanks.

Checking google services:

```
private fun initializeGoogleApi() {
        if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(requireContext()) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS
        ) {
            initializeRecaptcha()
        } else {
            showRecaptchaError(msg = getString(R.string.captcha_error))
        }
    }
```

Initializing Recaptcha Client:

```
private fun initializeRecaptcha() {
        val appInfo: ApplicationInfo = requireContext().packageManager.getApplicationInfo(
            requireContext().packageName,
            PackageManager.GET_META_DATA
        )
        val siteKey: String? = appInfo.metaData.getString("recaptcha.site_key")

        siteKey?.let { key: String ->
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                Recaptcha.getClient(application = requireActivity().application, siteKey = key)
                    .onSuccess { recaptchaClient = it }
                    .onFailure { showRecaptchaError(msg = getString(captcha_error2)) }
            }

        }
            ?: showRecaptchaError(msg = getString(captcha_error3))
    }
```

Triggered when button is clicked:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
                    recaptchaClient.execute(recaptchaAction = RecaptchaAction.custom(customAction = "forgot_password"))
                        .onSuccess {
                            Log.e("Recaptcha Token", it)
                        }
                        .onFailure { showRecaptchaError(msg = getString(captcha_error4)) }
                }
```